# Pasar tipo de clase de forma dinamica sobre un metodo en c#

Tags: c#

### Partiendo de:

Modelo persona

```
  public class Persona
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    [Required]
}
```

Modelo Buzon

```
public class Buzon
{

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int NumTicket { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
}
```

Método que realiza una consulta a Mongo

```
  public string GetCollectionExcludeFields(string nameCollection, string[] campos)
    {
        String camposFormato = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= campos.Length-1; i++)
        {
            if (i == campos.Length - 1)
            {
                camposFormato += campos[i] + ":1";
            }
            else
            {
                camposFormato += campos[i] + ":1,";
            }
        }
//Aquí, remplazar ese tipo estatico Project<Persona> a dinámico
        return db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(nameCollection).Find(x => true).Project<Persona>("{"+ camposFormato + "}").ToList().ToJson();


    }
```

**Mi pregunta:** ¿Es posible pasar de forma dinamica la clase "Persona"?, algo como:

```
 public string GetCollectionExcludeFields(string nameCollection, string[] campos,tipoclase clase)
{
    String camposFormato = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= campos.Length-1; i++)
    {
        if (i == campos.Length - 1)
        {
            camposFormato += campos[i] + ":1";
        }
        else
        {
            camposFormato += campos[i] + ":1,";
        }
    }
//Aquí, remplazar ese tipo estatico Project<Persona> a dinámico Project<clase>
    return db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(nameCollection).Find(x => true).Project<clase>("{"+ camposFormato + "}").ToList().ToJson();


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo con [esta guía de programación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) lo que necesitas hacer es definir tu método `GetCollectionExcludeFields` con una especificación de tipo genérico (el `<T>` junto al nombre del método):

```
public string GetCollectionExcludeFields<T>(string nameCollection, string[] campos)
{
    String camposFormato = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= campos.Length-1; i++)
    {
        if (i == campos.Length - 1)
        {
            camposFormato += campos[i] + ":1";
        }
        else
        {
            camposFormato += campos[i] + ":1,";
        }
    }

    return db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(nameCollection).Find(x =>true)
        .Project<T>("{"+ camposFormato + "}").ToList().ToJson();
}
```

Y lo ejecutas así:

```
GetCollectionExcludeFields<Persona>(...);
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta @Kroneaux Schneider, muchas gracias